# Making a description field - Reading and writing to it ina MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, mysqli

I'm creating an application with AngularJS and PHP. In that application is a `description` field, which does not have a character limit. Ultimately I'm trying to save the `description` field with `mysqli`, but am having difficulty choosing a datatype.

Because there is no character limit `VARCHAR` doesn't work. I made the field a `BLOB`. I don't know how to pass the long text to `mysqli` if it is a `BLOB`, nor do I know how to read it and write it into a `JSON` object, or how to read it in AngularJS so that the text can be loaded back into the `textarea` after saving.

Comment: You can use the type text, that works like varchar but without a 255 length limit.

Comment: @PabloDigiani `VARCHAR` columns do not have such a length limit in todays storage engines.

Comment: You don't have to deal somehow special with such a column type. I also suggest you use a variant of the `TEXT` type, but you can treat it just like any other column type. The difference to a `VARCHAR` type only is that the actual storage location is not within the table itself, but outside. That makes the table handling faster.

Comment: God, I feel so rusty, don't even remembered of TEXT datatype. Is there anything I should worry if I use it?

Comment: Well, escape your content and take care about character encoding, I'd say. Oh, and put in a few nice rhymes now and then :-)